# how to add number of days to custom date in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, solaris

I have a custom date returned from SQL query as "20-JUL-2015".I want to add/subtract x number of days from this custom date.How can I do it.

My Operating system is UNIX solaris, so `date -d` and `--date` option is not available.

Comment: Either write your own function (`awk` might be of help), or find one on the internet.

Comment: Another easier way would be to let SQL do it - if you have connection, you can do the math on the database. Would this match your requirement?

Comment: @chomel , I cannot use SQL MATH as this date returned from sqlquery sometime it might be blank. Is there any single perl command which i can user here in my bash script?

Comment: @Elloit your post mentioned has requirement of installing tclsh in server which cannot be possible in my case as we have many servers.